# C# server program hangs when multi clients connects

Tags: c#, sqlite, http, https

Greetings!

I have a c# console application which is installed as windows service in live machine. This application acts as server and uses http and https services. To commuunicate with client URLS's Tiny HTTP server open source is used. There are 90 clients using accessing the data from server using a client program which is developed using flex. This flex application connect to server as below,

Login url

```
try
{
   if(!Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains("https"))
        System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Lock);
   if (Request.Method == Method.Post)
   {
      SiteSession siteSession = _login( Request.Form["SiteName"].Value.Trim(),
                                        Request.Form["UserName"].Value.Trim(),
                                        Request.Form["Password"].Value.Trim());
      if (siteSession != null)
      {
           if (siteSession.authenticated)
           {
              User currentUser = siteSession.thingzDatabase.currentUser;
              _database = siteSession.thingzDatabase;

                             --------
```

item/detail urls like http:\domainname:port\item\detail\temid 
one client calls nearly 70 url's and get data from server database.So totaly 90+ clients

when item/list is called below code is performed.

```
if (Id == "")
{
   //System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_locker);
   System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Lock);
   try
   {
     if (Request.AcceptTypes == null)
     {

        TypeController.session_id = Request.QueryString["sessionid"].Value;

        //queue.   
        Enqueue(Request.QueryString["sessionid"].Value);

        //string que = "";

        ////do
        ////{
        //que = queue.Dequeue();
        //TypeController.session_id = que;

        langStr = SessionDatabase.Language;
        filter = new AllThingzFilter(SessionDatabase, parameters, langStr);

        TypeController.session_id = null;

        filter.Execute();
                                 --------
```

There is one administrator who updates/ writes the data to the server database using secure https service with different port number.
same login url calls and other post and get methods will be called in admin login.

Database used in server is sqlite. Now let me explain my problem,
I have received complaint from client saying server gets hanged and administrator cannot be able to login . Or if login not able to upload any images as soon any update to database is performed the server hangs. So need to restart the windows service again.

When admin perform the CRUD operations to the server db. At the same time client application( flex) application try to get the data from server as well.This url calls from client applicatuon every 5 mins once.

What could be the issue and how can i solve this server hand. Is it a read or write issue to sqlite db.
Please help me with valuable suggessions.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: You probably need to add some tracing and/or logging to the server app. This should give you more information as to where an errors are occurring.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly related to your locking code; if you're not careful to minimize the locked region and properly release them, it's easy to deadlock the server.

Comment: @Sangeetha. When you say the server hangs, do you mean that the windows service has stopped, or that it is still running but non-responsive?

Comment: Yes, windows service has stopped

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to separate ASP.NET Web role/membership functions from that DB CRUD operations: the latter should either implement its own autonomous security model, or to use the input from role/membership classes.

Comment: No asp.net application is included in this project . backend is c# for handling http request and for database. front end is flex application.

Comment: c# a console application and installed as a windows service inside production machine.